# UITableView: click on cells and open the link in cells with UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview, bookmarks

I have a `UIWebView` with a Bookmark button. The bookmarks are saved within a `UITableView`. The name of the cell is the link of the bookmark. Now I want to click the cells and then the url of the bookmark should loud in my webview. But it does not work, when i click on the cells.
This is my code for this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [bookmarks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    explorerView.urlField.text = [bookmarks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [explorerView textFieldShouldReturn:explorerView.urlField];
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:true];
}
```

Can you please give me a code example how to do this? This would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing actual code, that will load URL in `UIWebView`. You should add something like following code to your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
NSString *URLString = [bookmarks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString: URLString];
NSURLRequest *URLRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URLRequest];
[webView loadURLRequest:URLRequest];
```

Comment: Thank you for fast reply, but I have this code already, but it does not work

Comment: Or maybe it is working, but I can't see it, because my uitableview is still there. How can I show my viewcontroller with the uiwebview to the user?

Comment: Hmm, I assumed that your table view controller presented over view controller with `UIWebView`. In this case after `[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:true]` call you should see your web view. By the way, please, use `YES` (Objective-C) instead of `true` (C++).

Comment: No, thats not the case. I have one ViewController for the webview. Then I have a slide out menu where you have a cell called "Bookmarks". And from this cell you reach the tableview with all bookmarks. And from here I want to get back to my first viewcontroller with the webview, which is presenting the bookmarked page. Sorry for the "true". Im very new in objective c and I coded before in c++

Comment: I tried this:  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard   storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Identifier"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES]; But now i have a thread 1: signal SIGABRT error

Comment: It really depends on how your slide out menu is implemented. If you used `pushViewController:animated:` to present it, you should use `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` to hide it. If you use some custom 3rd-party component, it should have some method to hide menu. It's very hard to guess without access to code itself

Comment: If you need to unwind segue, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH15-SW1

Comment: OK, i made it very difficult to understand it for you, so I explain it simple: The slide out menu is not the problem. I'm in the table view menu. Normally I generate here cells on my own and connect them with the view controllers. But now they are generated by the user (the bookmarks), so I can not link them to any view controller. How can I do this programmatically? Normally i did this through the storyboard.

Comment: Take a look on the following question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers - hope it helps